# Read excel column having all cell values in dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core

I want to read excel file having a column having all cell values in dropdown. I am trying to read Excel interop but it seems there is some issue with .net core.
Please suggest the way how I can read excel file having dropdown cell or get all values of dropdown columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some ideas:

See Wolfwyrd answer here:
[Read Excel data from Drop down into C# object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524672/read-excel-data-from-drop-down-into-c-sharp-object-array)

See Chenchen Li answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ba0826d-0341-495c-8da3-b5f6c8ab95cf/reading-dropdown-cell-in-excel-file-using-microsoft-interop-excel?forum=exceldev
-> There is a VB Code to read the selected value from the dropdown, which translates easily in C#

I suggest, if you know the worksheet and the column where all the dropdown values are stored, you can read it from there. Check this answer from Brantley Blanchard for a code suggestion:
[Read Excel First Column using C# into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886330/read-excel-first-column-using-c-sharp-into-array)

I hope this helped :)

Comment: Already tried but .net core not support Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, please suggest other